# Can Byte Buddy use the advice method to handle things like "==", "!=", "<", ">" in the program?

Tags: java, jvm, byte-buddy

I want to use Byte Buddy's advice method in a Java program to monitor the following comparisons, such as

```
"1<2", "3>2", "param1!=null", "param3==param2"
```

Can these comparison operators be monitored with Byte Buddy? Such as using

```
@Advice.OnMethodEnter
```

If it is possible, is there any sample code for reference?

Comment: Those are not methods, but operators, so I **guess** the answer is no.

Comment: Can ASM perform such operations while the JVM is running?

Comment: This feels like a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). Can you tell us what underlying problem you're trying to solve? I suspect the attempted solution you want to get to is either impossible or very cumbersome to implement, but if you told us underlying feature you're trying to build, we could suggest alternative approaches that might be simpler.

Comment: I want to make a branch detection tool for java programs by myself, for example: if(str.euqals("string") && param1==param2), by checking whether these operators are executed during the running process. between the two What is the comparison result between them? Functions like euqals() can be easily detected by byte buddy, but the use of operators is unavoidable in the program. I don’t know how to do this, and I don’t know if ASM can implement it my thoughts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Advice is not capable of this. Normally, it does not make much sense to aim for such detailed elements as code changes to frequently, but you would need to use ASM to manipulate such code.